# Making hexgrid in QGIS with cell identification numbers?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, hexagonal-grid

I'm getting started with QGIS as part of my interest in military science and wargaming.  I'm running into a problem adding identifiers (column and row) to the hexcells that I've created with mmqgis.

This image gives an example of what I want to include.

[image: Example]

Comment: Create a python script that will place points in a hexagon grid with IDs and then create a Thiessen mesh using the attributes of the points. Hex Grids are not often used so there is no utility (that I know of) that will create one.

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating fields for X and Y coordinates of the centroids.  All of the Y coordinates will be the same for each column.  You can select those and call them '01', '02', '03', etc.  Then do the same for the rows.

You can easily write a script to sort by Y coords then X coords and rename columns and rows.

I just did a similar thing in ArcGIS. Except, my rows are numbered in reverse to yours.

Note, I created my hexagons in **[GME Spatial Modelling Environment](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/genhexagonsinpolys.htm)**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There was a nice blog post from esri speaking about how to divide a study area in hexagons.

[image]

[A new tool for creating sampling hexagons](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/05/06/a-new-tool-for-creating-sampling-hexagons/)

Surprisingly enough the author made a toolbox for arcmap which does what it advertises.

---

As a sidenote, hexagons are the highest-sided tessellable regular polygon which makes them extremely important in many fields.

A cool article descrbing hexagons can be seen at [hexnet.org](http://hexnet.org/content/hexagonal-geometry)

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS there are multiple options. Either way, you would use label expressions and `concat` fields and any delimiters as needed. Then just set the label to be offset to top and increase the Y offset as needed.

These come to mind:

1. You could do everything through the label expression. The produced hexes all have left/top/bottom/right fields. Looking up min and max values for left and top, you could calculate the target position through a bit of linear algebra.
2. If you look at the way the hexes follow each other, you'll noticed they are numbered from bottom to top, left to right. If you populate a new field with `@row_number`, you'll get exactly what @Fezter provided.

   If you rotate the grid by 90°, you can get it to run from top to bottom, left to right. Then you can use the attribute table to create two new fields to hold the column and row index. You can compute them via `@row_number` modulo number of cells in that dimension. *However*, the staggered dimension will probably be problematic and require more work.
3. Create an overlapping rectangular grid layer that would only display labels. Craft it with such dimensions, that labels would be placed correctly for both staggered and non-staggered cells. Since you're dealing with rectangles, it's now probably easier to write a label expression that will show only the desired labels (skip superfluous ones).